# Launching Spring application Address already in use

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, spring-mvc

I have this error launching my spring application:

```
java -jar target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::             (v0.5.0.M6)

2013-12-23 00:23:09.466  INFO 19252 --- [           main] hello.Application                        : Starting Application on mbp-de-antoine.home with PID 19252 (/Users/antoine/Documents/workspace-sts-3.4.0.RELEASE/springapp/target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar started by antoine)
2013-12-23 00:23:09.511  INFO 19252 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@24024c39: startup date [Mon Dec 23 00:23:09 CET 2013]; root of context hierarchy
2013-12-23 00:23:10.910  INFO 19252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2013-12-23 00:23:10.910  INFO 19252 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.42
2013-12-23 00:23:11.045  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2013-12-23 00:23:11.046  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1537 ms
2013-12-23 00:23:11.274  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2013-12-23 00:23:11.274  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
2013-12-23 00:23:11.409  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-12-23 00:23:11.634  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/greeting],methods=[],params=[],headers=[],consumes=[],produces=[],custom=[]}" onto public java.lang.String hello.GreetingController.greeting(java.lang.String,org.springframework.ui.Model)
2013-12-23 00:23:11.717  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-12-23 00:23:11.717  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2013-12-23 00:23:12.406  INFO 19252 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 1132 ms
2013-12-23 00:23:12.417 ERROR 19252 --- [           main] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:617)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1010)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:738)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

2013-12-23 00:23:12.419 ERROR 19252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:459)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:732)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:335)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:738)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:12)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1017)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:444)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:436)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:214)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:473)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:617)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1010)
    ... 25 common frames omitted

2013-12-23 00:23:12.420  INFO 19252 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service Tomcat
2013-12-23 00:23:12.430  INFO 19252 --- [           main] nitializer$AutoConfigurationReportLogger : 


=========================
AUTO-CONFIGURATION REPORT
=========================


Positive matches:
-----------------

   MessageSourceAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.MessageSource; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   PropertyPlaceholderAutoConfiguration#propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.DefaultTemplateResolverConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: defaultTemplateResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafDefaultConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.thymeleaf.spring3.SpringTemplateEngine; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafViewResolverConfiguration#thymeleafViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (names: thymeleafViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: all) found the following [tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory] (OnBeanCondition)

   DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration#dispatcherServlet
      - no DispatcherServlet found (DispatcherServletAutoConfiguration.DefaultDispatcherServletCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedTomcat
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory; SearchStrategy: current) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   ServerPropertiesAutoConfiguration#serverProperties
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.properties.ServerProperties; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - found web application StandardServletEnvironment (OnWebApplicationCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet,org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration#hiddenHttpMethodFilter
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#defaultViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)


Negative matches:
-----------------

   RabbitAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate,com.rabbitmq.client.Channel (OnClassCondition)

   AopAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect,org.aspectj.lang.reflect.Advice (OnClassCondition)

   BatchAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.batch.core.launch.JobLauncher (OnClassCondition)

   JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository (OnClassCondition)

   MongoRepositoriesAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: com.mongodb.Mongo,org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.embedded.EmbeddedDatabaseType (OnClassCondition)

   DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate,org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager (OnClassCondition)

   JmsTemplateAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate,javax.jms.ConnectionFactory (OnClassCondition)

   DeviceResolverAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceResolverHandlerInterceptor,org.springframework.mobile.device.DeviceHandlerMethodArgumentResolver (OnClassCondition)

   HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement,javax.persistence.EntityManager,org.hibernate.ejb.HibernateEntityManager (OnClassCondition)

   ReactorAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: reactor.spring.context.config.EnableReactor (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafSecurityDialectConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.thymeleaf.extras.springsecurity3.dialect.SpringSecurityDialect (OnClassCondition)

   ThymeleafAutoConfiguration.ThymeleafWebLayoutConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf.LayoutDialect (OnClassCondition)

   EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration.EmbeddedJetty
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server,org.eclipse.jetty.util.Loader (OnClassCondition)

   MultipartAutoConfiguration
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnClass classes found: javax.servlet.Servlet,org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver (OnClassCondition)
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: javax.servlet.MultipartConfigElement; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#beanNameViewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebMvcAutoConfiguration.WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter#viewResolver
      - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.web.servlet.View; SearchStrategy: all) found no beans (OnBeanCondition)

   WebSocketAutoConfiguration
      - required @ConditionalOnClass classes not found: org.springframework.web.socket.WebSocketHandler (OnClassCondition)



java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embdedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:138)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:476)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:552)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:293)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:749)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:738)
    at hello.Application.main(Application.java:12)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embdedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:85)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.<init>(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:53)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getTomcatEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:259)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.getEmbeddedServletContainer(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:158)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:135)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.initialize(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:81)
    ... 18 more
```

I think this is because my port is used. My port 8080 is used so I try the port 8181
I have no application on the port 8181

in the tomcat server.xml I set the port to 8181 but the problem persist

I find this post:

[Alternate port for Tomcat (not 8080) when starting with Maven?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/646649/alternate-port-for-tomcat-not-8080-when-starting-with-maven)

But I have the same problem  after launching mvn -Dmaven.tomcat.port=8181 tomcat:run-war

I don't realy understand how to maven is linked to the tomcat server
This is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>gs-serving-web-content</artifactId>
    <version>0.1.0</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.5.0.M6</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <properties>
        <start-class>hello.Application</start-class>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

</project>
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: First make sure that these ports are 'really' available to begin with. Now I guess that you are using some *Unix system ( I am guessing from the path delimiter), open your terminal and run `netstat -tuplen` to get a complete list of used ports with their respective processIDs. Verify from there whether the ports are free of used before starting tomcat

Comment: Yes my port 8181 is free

Comment: check whether the default port(8080) is running or not. In Windows use > netstat -a -o -n and then search your port no whether is running or not.... if it is running then note the pid corresponding it. taskkill /f /pid {pidno}

Comment: Also wrong IP in configuration file causes this exception.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Spring Boot uses embedded Tomcat by default, but it handles it differently without using `tomcat-maven-plugin`. To change the port use [`--server.port`](http://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/spring-boot/README.html#toc_3) parameter for example:

```
java -jar target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar --server.port=8181
```

**Update**. Alternatively put `server.port=8181` into `application.properties` (or `application.yml`).

Comment: Is it possible to set it in configurations? For example using annotation?

Comment: Putting `server.port=8181` into your application.properties file should also work.

Comment: Don't forget to clean and build...that also helps

Comment: A better option for the application.properties file is including a default with the override ability server.port=${port:8181}

Comment: Thanks a lot man!! I've searching that solution whole day and after adding --server.port=8181 it solved. thanks

Comment: I got the same error: tried **netstat -tulpn | grep 8080** to find the process and tried to kill it , but no luck :(

Comment: For me the error is caused by the "standalone" tomcat8 which was still running (using the same 8080 port) I just had to execute the command `sudo systemctrl stop tomcat8` (in Arch Linux).

Comment: For yml it's: server: port: 8181

Comment: Why this error , Unable to access jarfile target/gs-serving-web-content-0.1.0.jar

Answer (score 63):

Run the following command to search for the process that is using the port

```
lsof -i :<portNumber> | grep LISTEN
```

in your case this will be -->

```
lsof -i :8080 | grep LISTEN
java    78960 xyxss  119u  IPv6 0x6c20d372bc88c27d      0t0  TCP *:8092 (LISTEN)
```

The 78960 is the process id, use the following command to kill the process

```
kill -9 78960
```

Launch the application again.

Comment: I had to use this command to get it to work on my mac: sudo lsof  -n -P | grep LISTEN. Mac will prompt you to type in your password as you are using sudo.

Comment: Thanks for Answer here. Only this solution works with IntelliJ

Comment: I have macOS Big Sur and this perfectly works. Thanks.

Answer (score 30):

Configure another port number(eg:8181) in */src/main/resources/application.properties*

> server.port=8181

Comment: @Junchen Lui That's because it is just a workaround. If you do this all the time, you will have a lot of unused tomcats running. Better fix the error in first place.

Comment: dam, this really works without configuring any xml or setup projecto

Answer (score 13):

You need to stop the server before re-launching. Look for the red box icon or server view.

Comment: yes, that was problem in eclipse. Here is how to stop Tomcat in NetBeans: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/543439/stop-tomcat-when-run-inside-of-netbeans

Answer (score 8):

This error basically happens when the specific port is not free. So there are two solutions, you can free that port by killing or closing the service which is using it or you can run your application (tomcat) on a different port.

### **Solution 1: Free the port**

On a Linux machine you can find the process-id of port's consumer and then kill it. Use the following command (it is assume that the default port is 8080)

```
netstat -pnltu | grep -i "8080"
```

The output of the above-mentioned command would be something like:

```
tcp6   0  0 :::8080    :::*      LISTEN      20674/java
```

Then you can easily kill the process with its processid:

```
kill 20674
```

On a windows machine to find a processid use `netstat -ano -p tcp |find "8080"`. To kill the process use `taskkill /F /PID 1234` (instead of 1234 enter the founded processid).

### **Solution 2: Change the default port**

In the development process developers use the `port 8080` that you can change it easily. You need to specify your desired port number in the `application.properties` file of your project (`/src/main/resources/application.properties`) by using the following specification:

```
server.port=8081
```

You can also set an alternative port number while executing the `.jar` file

```
- java -jar spring-boot-application.jar --server.port=8081
```

Please notice that sometimes (not necessarily) you have to change other ports too like:

```
management.port=
tomcat.jvmroute=
tomcat.ajp.port=
tomcat.ajp.redirectPort=
etc...
```

Answer (score 6):

[image: image of Spring Tool Suite and stop application button]

In my case looking in the servers window only showed a tomcat server that I had never used for this project.  My SpringBoot project used an embedded tomcat server and it did not stop when my application finished.  This button which I indicate with a red arrow will stop the application and the Tomcat server so next time I run the application I will not get the error that an Instance of Tomcat is already running on port 8080.

actual error messages:

> Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process
> that's listening on port 8080, or configure this application to listen
> on another port.
>
> Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use Caused by:
> org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";
> Protocol handler start failed

I will now be looking into a way to shut down all services on completion of my SpringBoot Consuming Rest application in this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/

## spring-boot

Answer (score 4):

Using IntelliJ, I got this error when I tried to run a Spring app while there was one app already running. I had to stop the first one. After that, running the second app didn't return any errors.

Answer (score 4):

first, check that who uses port 8080.

- telnet localhost 8080
- use browser to open http://localhost:8080

if the port 8080 is in use, change the listening port to 8181.

if you use IDEA, modify start configuration, 
Run-> Edit Configuration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j4qEz.png)

if you use mvn spring-boot, then use the command:

```
mvn spring-boot:run -Dserver.port=8181
```

if you use java -jar, then use the command:

```
java -jar xxxx.jar --server.port=8181
```

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to kill the port number. It worked for me

```
netstat -ano | findstr :yourPortNumber taskkill /PID typeyourPIDhere /F
```

Answer (score 3):

you can configure another port number in your IDE
 **/src/main/resources/application.properties**

server.port=8081

otherwise right click on the IDE **console** tab and select **Terminate/Disconnect All**

Comment: I don't know, some process has occupied the port 5000, hence used the another port, sometime we just mess with the issues, even small thing we don't change, yes after changing port, its working great.

Answer (score 2):

This only worked for me by setting additional properties and using available arbitrary port numbers, like this:

- YML

/src/main/resources/application.yml

```
server:
  port: 18181
management:
  port: 9191
tomcat:
  jvmroute: 5478
  ajp:
    port: 4512
    redirectPort: 1236
```

- Properties

/src/main/resources/application.properties

```
server.port=18181
management.port=9191
tomcat.jvmroute=5478
tomcat.ajp.port=4512
tomcat.ajp.redirectPort=1236
```

Comment: This worked for me. In Spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE, the `management.port` key is replaced with `management.server.port`.

Comment: tomcat.jvmroute=5478 helped me to run two instances of the application along with server.port=18181

Answer (score 2):

In your **application.properties** file -

*/src/main/resources/**application.properties***

Change the port number to something like this -

**server.port=8181**

Or alternatively you can provide alternative port number while executing your jar file -
**java -jar resource-server/build/libs/resource-server.jar --server.port=8888**

Answer (score 2):

Right click in console and click Terminate/Disconnect All option.

OR

Click on 'Display selected console' icon on top right corner of the console window and, choose and terminate the console which holds the port still.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, Oracle TNS Service was using port 8080, found that using running the command "netstat - anob" as an administrator. Simply used Shutdown Database from the Windows start menu to stop that service and was able to start the SpringBoot app without any issue.

Also if you cannot find out which app is using the 8080 port and just want to run the SprintBoot app, you can click on Run As... and in the VM arguments enter: 
-Dserver.port=0 (this will pick any random available port) or you can be specific like: -Dserver.port=8081

Hope it helps.

Comment: I tried changing my -Dserver.port=0 and tested with two applications, launched at the same time. Now both open in different port

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this following these steps:

1. Right click on the project you are running.
2. Click on *Run as* and *Run Configurations* from the option.
3. A new run configuration will open. Under *Spring Boot Tab* see for *Override properties*.
4. Add the property-value pair as `server.port=8181`, or any other port of your choice. This will override the default port which is 8080

Answer (score 1):

It is really old question. Maybe this is usefull. Focusing in your title problem, it is how I start my applications and then I can easily shutdown them. Change the port number for each application you want to start as mentioned above.

application.properties

```
#using curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown to avoid:
#netstat -ano | find "8080"
#taskkill /F /PID xxxx (xxxx stands for PID)
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
management.endpoint.shutdown.enabled=true
endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true
```

add this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now you can shotdown easily by

```
curl -X POST localhost:8080/actuator/shutdown
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution for Windows but didn't found any.
Finally, figured out that that there is a dangling java application using the port. Maybe it's the earlier instance of the spring application and ended the process.

I used [tcpview from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/sysinternals/downloads/tcpview). It shows services/applications using which port on your computer.

[image]

You can end the process. And Done!

Answer (score 1):

This is because the port is already running in the background.So you can restart the eclipse and try again.
OR
open the file application.properties and change the value of 'server.port' to some other value like ex:- 8000/8181

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem, by **stop the application** (red square in Eclipse) before run again.
If you don't stop it , the application stay in run mode , so port still used .

Answer (score 0):

You have another process that’s listening on port 8080 which is the default port that’s used by Spring Boot’s web support. You either need to stop that process or configure your app to listen on another port.

You can change the port configuration by adding **server.port=4040** (for example) to **src/main/resources/application.properties**

Answer (score 0):

Basically the default server usually run on the background at port 8080.
Open services.msc and stop tomcat server and try running the spring boot application again.

Answer (score 0):

In Eclipse, if Spring Tool Suite is installed, you can go to **Boot Dashboard** and expand local in explorer and right click on the application that is running on port 8080 and stop it before you re run your application.

Answer (score 0):

I try to change port number in the following file - /src/main/resources/application-prod.yml

And inside this file I made this change:

server:
    port: 8100  (or whatever you want)

I hope that this will works good for you

Answer (score 0):

Just met same problem.

Finally I found the process running on 8080 was owned by other user, such as root. which caused I (user dev) can't find it by `lsof -i :8080` or `lsof -t -i :8080 -s TCP:LISTEN`.

Answer (score -1):

Close the application, then restart it after changing to a new port:

```
${port:8181}
```

You can use any new unused port. Here, I used port 8181.

Comment: @Bruce How does this not attempt to provide an answer? I see a clear attempt: closing the application; changing the port; and restarting it. It might be completely wrong, but that doesn't mean it's not an attempt to answer.

Answer (score -1):

I was getting same issue, i.e. **protocol handler start failed**. Cause was **port is already in use**. I found whether the port was in use or not. It was. So I killed the process that was running on that port and restarted my spring boot application. And it worked. :)