# Hygieia Installation Error

Tags: spring, api, hygieia

We got this error while Hygieia dashboard installation.  Please confirm if anyone has come across this. this looks related to spring boot   and got it while I was installing the UI for Hygieia

```
2017-07-11 20:50:41,551 ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application startup failed
org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:
1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0
.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1
.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.R
ELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134) [spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.0.RELEASE]
        at com.capitalone.dashboard.Application.main(Application.java:37) [api.jar!/:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53) [api.jar!/:2.0.5-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_131]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159) ~[spring-boot-1.3.0.RELEASE.jar!/:
1.3.0.RELEASE]
        ... 15 common frames omitted
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:53)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat servlet container
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:165)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.startEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:290)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.finishRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:141)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.doRun(SpringApplication.java:347)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:295)
        at org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder.run(SpringApplicationBuilder.java:134)
        at com.capitalone.dashboard.Application.main(Application.java:37)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Tomcat connector in failed state
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.start(TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer.java:159)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Have you checked your ports? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735205/launching-spring-application-address-already-in-use It seems that such exception may be thrown if your tomcat port is already in use

Answer (score 0):

Is this the full log ? You should always send the complete log.

Besides your question is wrong, there is nothing to install as far as Hygieia is considered.
there are simple steps that one needs to follow, namely -

1.Get the repo in you system

2.setup all the requirements of Hygieia (Mongodb, maven etc etc)

3.**mvn clean install** on the root directory

4. Create proper properties file for the jars
5. Run Hygieia

But Even I have faced a lot of problems with setting up Hygieia, so you should take care of these -

1. Always get the fresh/latest code from github
2. If you are on corporate/Company N/W then do ensure you have proxies to maven and system proxy setup.

If you add the full trace log then I just might get the problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to follow some steps

1. Download Hygieia rep from this link:
   https://github.com/Hygieia/Hygieia
2. Install maven and java :- 
   https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-apache-maven-on-ubuntu-18-04/
3. Also need to download subdivision-collector folder inside this directory 
   Hygieia/collectors/scm:-
   https://github.com/Hygieia/hygieia-scm-subversion-collector
4. Now open \Hygieia folder and run

   $ mvn  clean install