# Unable to start spring boot application - java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to start my first spring boot rest application but its failing to start with below exceptions.

I have tried the solutions mentioned in below link but still its not working.

[Launching Spring application Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735205/launching-spring-application-address-already-in-use) `launching spring application`

I made sure no application in running in port 8080. Also tried changing the port number by setting server.port = 7090 in application properties file still i'm unsuccessful.

Any thoughts?

```
C:\Users\krupa>netstat -a -n -o | find "8080"
C:\Users\krupa>netstat -a -n -o | find "7090"
```

Application.java

```
package com.example.springrestful.demo.restfulservices;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
server.address=localhost
server.port=7091
```

POM file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example.springrestful</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo.restfulservices</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>demo.restfulservices</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-snapshots</id>
            <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/snapshot</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>


</project>
```

Console logs:

```
16:45:18.638 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Included patterns for restart : []
16:45:18.642 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.settings.DevToolsSettings - Excluded patterns for restart : [/spring-boot-starter/target/classes/, /spring-boot-autoconfigure/target/classes/, /spring-boot-starter-[\w-]+/, /spring-boot/target/classes/, /spring-boot-actuator/target/classes/, /spring-boot-devtools/target/classes/]
16:45:18.642 [main] DEBUG org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.ChangeableUrls - Matching URLs for reloading : [file:/E:/Education/spring-microservices/demo.restfulservices/target/classes/]

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::  (v2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT)

2017-12-25 16:45:19.070  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.demo.restfulservices.Application   : Starting Application on KIPI with PID 11904 (E:\Education\spring-microservices\demo.restfulservices\target\classes started by ganesh in E:\Education\spring-microservices\demo.restfulservices)
2017-12-25 16:45:19.070  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] c.e.s.demo.restfulservices.Application   : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-25 16:45:19.195  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@104b00ce: startup date [Mon Dec 25 16:45:19 MST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-25 16:45:21.729  INFO 11904 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2017-12-25 16:45:22.105  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 7091 (http)
2017-12-25 16:45:22.121  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.121  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-12-25 16:45:22.152  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_152\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_152/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Dev\ojdbc14.jar;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\x64;C:\Program Files (x86)\HP SimplePass\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Live\Shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\3.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_152;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.3.9\bin;C:\Program Files\Amazon\AWSCLI\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Users\krupa\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Dev\eclipse-jee-oxygen-1a-win32-x86_64\eclipse;;.]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.371  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-25 16:45:22.371  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3176 ms
2017-12-25 16:45:22.644  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.645  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'webServlet' to [/h2-console/*]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.645  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.645  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.645  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.645  INFO 11904 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-25 16:45:22.911  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Starting...
2017-12-25 16:45:23.570  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Start completed.
2017-12-25 16:45:23.729  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-25 16:45:23.759  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-12-25 16:45:23.868  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.12.Final}
2017-12-25 16:45:23.868  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-12-25 16:45:23.915  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.0.1.Final}
2017-12-25 16:45:24.067  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2017-12-25 16:45:24.332  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2017-12-25 16:45:24.395  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.t.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl  : HHH000476: Executing import script 'org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.ScriptSourceInputNonExistentImpl@21259451'
2017-12-25 16:45:24.395  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-25 16:45:24.638  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.h.v.i.engine.ValidatorFactoryImpl      : HV000238: Temporal validation tolerance set to 0.
2017-12-25 16:45:25.114  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@104b00ce: startup date [Mon Dec 25 16:45:19 MST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-25 16:45:25.187  WARN 11904 --- [  restartedMain] aWebConfiguration$JpaWebMvcConfiguration : spring.jpa.open-in-view is enabled by default. Therefore, database queries may be performed during view rendering. Explicitly configure spring.jpa.open-in-view to disable this warning
2017-12-25 16:45:25.281  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2017-12-25 16:45:25.281  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2017-12-25 16:45:25.375  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-25 16:45:25.375  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-25 16:45:25.469  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2017-12-25 16:45:25.831  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2017-12-25 16:45:26.018  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-12-25 16:45:26.018  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Bean with name 'dataSource' has been autodetected for JMX exposure
2017-12-25 16:45:26.034  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Located MBean 'dataSource': registering with JMX server as MBean [com.zaxxer.hikari:name=dataSource,type=HikariDataSource]
2017-12-25 16:45:47.130 ERROR 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol      : Failed to start end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-7091"]

java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:990) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1022) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) [tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:247) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:189) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:298) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) [spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.springrestful.demo.restfulservices.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

2017-12-25 16:45:47.149 ERROR 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-7091]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-7091]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:247) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:189) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:298) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:160) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) [spring-context-5.0.2.RELEASE.jar:5.0.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:138) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:751) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:387) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1245) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1233) [spring-boot-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.springrestful.demo.restfulservices.Application.main(Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT.jar:2.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: service.getName(): "Tomcat";  Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1031) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 18 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to establish loopback connection
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectorProviderImpl.openPipe(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.nio.channels.Pipe.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorImpl.<init>(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.WindowsSelectorProvider.openSelector(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.nio.channels.Selector.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector(NioSelectorPool.java:66) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.open(NioSelectorPool.java:130) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:990) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:635) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1022) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.23.jar:8.5.23]
    ... 19 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.nio.channels.SocketChannel.open(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.nio.ch.PipeImpl$Initializer$LoopbackConnector.run(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    ... 34 common frames omitted

2017-12-25 16:45:47.182  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-12-25 16:45:47.198  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-25 16:45:47.198 ERROR 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 7091 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 7091, or configure this application to listen on another port.

2017-12-25 16:45:47.198  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@104b00ce: startup date [Mon Dec 25 16:45:19 MST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-12-25 16:45:47.198  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2017-12-25 16:45:47.198  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2017-12-25 16:45:47.198  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-25 16:45:47.198  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] .SchemaDropperImpl$DelayedDropActionImpl : HHH000477: Starting delayed drop of schema as part of SessionFactory shut-down'
2017-12-25 16:45:47.214  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Shutdown initiated...
2017-12-25 16:45:47.214  INFO 11904 --- [  restartedMain] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : testdb - Shutdown completed.
```

Comment: The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 7091 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured. Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 7091, or configure this application to listen on another port.

Comment: Hi Roman, as mentioned earlier there is no service running on port 7091 in my machine. I executed below command and it didn't find any service on port 7091. netstat -a -n -o | find "7090"

Comment: [Check if port is open or closed on a Linux server?](https://serverfault.com/q/309052).

Comment: I'm getting below error message if i try to connect to that port.  C:\Users\krupa>telnet localhost 7091
Connecting To localhost...Could not open connection to the host, on port 7091: Connect failed

Comment: Are you setting server.address in your application.properties file?

Comment: Below is the application.properties configuration. I'm also adding the source file just in case if i'm making any mistake, please correct me.

server.address=localhost
server.port=7090

Comment: Can you kill the process against the port using below and try to start the server again..Lets see what happen.                                                                    
 netstat -ano | findstr :urPrtNo taskkill /PID urPid /F

Comment: I'm not sure is the port number is really the issue here. Because i can find specified port pid only if I start the server and execute below command. Otherwise i'm not able to find the pid. Is there any problem in the sample code given above. Its a simple hello world program.
netstat -ano | findstr :7090