# Java - Spring Boot - fails to start Web server on port 8080

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, webserver

I am going trough Spring boot configuration and testing setup and basic application.

Trying to run a Web Spring boot application from InteliJ:

```
package com.springbootdemoweb1.demoweb1;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoWeb1Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoWeb1Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

It is a very basic application but it show errors:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:TieredStopAtLevel=1 -noverify -Dspring.output.ansi.enabled=always -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=53736 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=127.0.0.1 -Dspring.liveBeansView.mbeanDomain -Dspring.application.admin.enabled=true "-javaagent:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/lib/idea_rt.jar=53737:/Applications/IntelliJ IDEA.app/Contents/bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/deploy.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/cldrdata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/dnsns.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jaccess.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/jfxrt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/localedata.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/nashorn.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunec.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunjce_provider.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/sunpkcs11.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext/zipfs.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/javaws.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfxswt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/management-agent.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/plugin.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/ant-javafx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/dt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/javafx-mx.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/jconsole.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/packager.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/sa-jdi.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_161.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar:/Users/dnk306/IdeaProjects/demo-web1/target/classes:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-web/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-autoconfigure/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-logging/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-classic/1.2.3/logback-classic-1.2.3.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/ch/qos/logback/logback-core/1.2.3/logback-core-1.2.3.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-to-slf4j/2.10.0/log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/apache/logging/log4j/log4j-api/2.10.0/log4j-api-2.10.0.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/jul-to-slf4j/1.7.25/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/javax/annotation/javax.annotation-api/1.3.2/javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/yaml/snakeyaml/1.19/snakeyaml-1.19.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-json/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-databind/2.9.4/jackson-databind-2.9.4.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-annotations/2.9.0/jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/jackson-core/2.9.4/jackson-core-2.9.4.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jdk8/2.9.4/jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.4.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310/2.9.4/jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.4.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/jackson/module/jackson-module-parameter-names/2.9.4/jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.4.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-tomcat/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-core/8.5.28/tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-el/8.5.28/tomcat-embed-el-8.5.28.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/apache/tomcat/embed/tomcat-embed-websocket/8.5.28/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.28.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/hibernate/validator/hibernate-validator/6.0.7.Final/hibernate-validator-6.0.7.Final.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/javax/validation/validation-api/2.0.1.Final/validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/jboss/logging/jboss-logging/3.3.2.Final/jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/com/fasterxml/classmate/1.3.4/classmate-1.3.4.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-web/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-web-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-beans/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-webmvc/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-webmvc-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-aop/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-aop-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-context/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-expression/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-expression-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-api/1.7.25/slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:/Users/dnk306/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-jcl/5.0.4.RELEASE/spring-jcl-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar com.springbootdemoweb1.demoweb1.DemoWeb1Application

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.0.RELEASE)

2018-03-02 14:06:24.863  INFO 7177 --- [           main] c.s.demoweb1.DemoWeb1Application         : Starting DemoWeb1Application on 9801a7a5b33d with PID 7177 (/Users/dnk306/IdeaProjects/demo-web1/target/classes started by dnk306 in /Users/dnk306/IdeaProjects/demo-web1)
2018-03-02 14:06:24.865  INFO 7177 --- [           main] c.s.demoweb1.DemoWeb1Application         : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-03-02 14:06:24.904  INFO 7177 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6e75aa0d: startup date [Fri Mar 02 14:06:24 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-02 14:06:25.641  INFO 7177 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2018-03-02 14:06:25.659  INFO 7177 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-03-02 14:06:25.659  INFO 7177 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.28
2018-03-02 14:06:25.662  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [/Users/dnk306/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.]
2018-03-02 14:06:25.730  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-03-02 14:06:25.730  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 830 ms
2018-03-02 14:06:25.807  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Servlet dispatcherServlet mapped to [/]
2018-03-02 14:06:25.812  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-02 14:06:25.812  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-02 14:06:25.812  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-02 14:06:25.812  INFO 7177 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2018-03-02 14:06:26.050  INFO 7177 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@6e75aa0d: startup date [Fri Mar 02 14:06:24 EST 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-03-02 14:06:26.101  INFO 7177 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2018-03-02 14:06:26.102  INFO 7177 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2018-03-02 14:06:26.125  INFO 7177 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-02 14:06:26.126  INFO 7177 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-02 14:06:26.153  INFO 7177 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2018-03-02 14:06:26.263  INFO 7177 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2018-03-02 14:06:26.295 ERROR 7177 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Failed to start connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]

org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:167) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.addConnector(StandardService.java:225) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.addPreviouslyRemovedConnectors(TomcatWebServer.java:255) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer.start(TomcatWebServer.java:197) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.startWebServer(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:300) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:162) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) [spring-context-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:752) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:388) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1246) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1234) [spring-boot-2.0.0.RELEASE.jar:2.0.0.RELEASE]
    at com.springbootdemoweb1.demoweb1.DemoWeb1Application.main(DemoWeb1Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler start failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1021) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 13 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:210) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.start(AbstractEndpoint.java:1150) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start(AbstractProtocol.java:591) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.startInternal(Connector.java:1018) ~[tomcat-embed-core-8.5.28.jar:8.5.28]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Sounds like port 8080 is busy but do not see anything that is running on that port:
netstat -a | grep 8080
lsof -i :80

What should I check?

Comment: can you add this `server.port=9090` in `application.properties` and test again with **localhost:9090**?

Comment: Thanks @YCF_L! This helped and made it work!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks very similar to a previous question: [Launching Spring application Address already in use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20735205/launching-spring-application-address-already-in-use).

You may already have the server running on that port, and need to stop it before relaunching.

You can also use a different port, such as 8181.

Answer (score 10):

Its strange that 8080 looks free, but still you get `Already in use` error.

I suggest you to set `server.port` in your config to some other port instead of default 8080 (say 8081) like any one of the below given options:

**1)** Add following to your application.properties -

```
server.port=8081
```

If you are using application.yml -

```
server:
     port: 8081
```

**2)** Give a command line option for defining the port -

```
java -jar pathToJar/jar-name-1.0.0.jar --server.port=8081
```

If using a IDE, in your build config add the following JVM argument -

```
-Dserver.port=8081
```